# Unable to install r-base due to errors '404 Not Found' and unmet dependencies

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, installation, google-compute-engine

I am unfamiliar with command-lines and trying to install R onto my Google Cloud VM instance. Here is the version of my Ubuntu.

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.2 (stretch)
Release:        9.2
Codename:       stretch
```

I have been using this link to guide me:  http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu

First, I added a deb repository into my source.list.
The line I added into the source.list is 'deb https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu utopic/'. 
Then I performed the following.

```
kefei@pectendashboard:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
kefei@pectendashboard:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 
keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Zdt2MbceSW/gpg.1.sh --keyserver 
keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not 
changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I would like to know what is meant by 'gpg:no valid OpenPGP data found.'

```
kefei@pectendashboard:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
The latest developmental version of R for testing packages
More info: https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rdev
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp3c2s3m12/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp3c2s3m12/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 5E25F516B04C661B: public key "Launchpad PPA for marutter" 
imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

More errors appear when I ran apt-get update, mainly 404 Errors. For example:

```
kefei@pectendashboard:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu 
bionic/main Translation-en_US   
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 
Packages                     
404  Not Found
```

This is then followed by a series of warning and error messages.

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic 
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu 
bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-
unstable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Rel
ease file.
E: Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-
amd64/Packages  
404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After this, I ran 'sudo apt-get upgrade' and 'sudo apt-get install r-base', obtaining the following messages.

```
kefei@pectendashboard:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.2-2xenial2) but it is not going 
to be installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.2-2xenial2) but it is not going to 
be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried numerous sources and repositories for installing r-base, but the same error messages keep on appearing. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.